# Can't Access Wordpress Backend

Tags: wordpress, authentication, backend

I've really got a conundrum here. I suddenly can't get into the backend of two of my websites. When I go to the /wp-login.php and log in, it just redirects to the home page, but I'm not loggged in. I didn't touch anything and automatic updates are turned off. 
Now here's the conundrum: I've deleted all files and the database a stuck a backup from last month on it, where everything was working fine. But it didn't fix the issue! Which kind of makes me think that the problem in on the server-level. 
What I also find wierd is that it happened to two websites at the same time. Anyone else have this problem oder any suggestions? Counld't find anything new on Google, just old stuff. 
Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit1: Here's my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: check it your .htaccess redirect file as well

Comment: let me know your current version of WordPress

Answer (score 0):

change in theme core file `functions.php`

```
// Block Access to /wp-admin for non admins.
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' ); // Hook into 'init'
```

All you have to do is add your own role capability, for example: `!current_user_can( 'manage-reports' )`

Comment: As far as I can tell with my bad code knowlage, this is redirecting me to the home page, if I'm not an admin? Anyway, I can't find any such code in my functions.php. Tried searching for wp_redirect, 0 results.

Comment: check it your .htaccess redirect file as well

Comment: I've posted my .htaccess in my original question. Is that what you mean by .htaccess redirect?

Comment: The .htaccess file is fine, disable the unused or newly installed plugin, if you not able to login WordPress dashboard. login into hosting the panel and go "wp-content/plugins" in under plugins folder rename the folder name the plugin will disabled

Comment: Renamed the whole Plugins folder, no changes.

Comment: Also, I feel like changing any FILES won't help, since this is a backup. And it worked, when I made the backup. As I said, and I may be wrong, I feel like this is server-based?

Comment: Try disabling all your plugins by moving or deleting them from your /wp-content/plugins/ folder. Do this by FTP or by your host's control panel.

Comment: No, that also didn't do it. Sorry for taking so much of your time.